# Why is np.compress faster than boolean indexing?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

What is `np.compress` doing internally that makes it faster than boolean indexing?

In this example, `compress` is ~20% faster, but the time savings varies on the size of `a` and the number of `True` values in the boolean array `b`, but on my machine `compress` is always faster.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(1000000,4)
b = (a[:,0]>0.5)

%timeit a[b]
#>>> 10 loops, best of 3: 24.7 ms per loop
%timeit a.compress(b, axis=0)
#>>> 10 loops, best of 3: 20 ms per loop
```

The [documentation for boolean indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) says

> What is returned is a copy of the data, not a view as one gets with slices

In contrast, the [compress docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.compress.html) say

> Return selected slices of an array along given axis".

However, using the [method provided here](http://ipython-books.github.io/featured-01/) for determining whether two arrays share the same data buffer shows that neither method shares data with its parent `a`, which I take to mean neither method returns an actual slice.

```
def get_data_base(arr):
    base = arr
    while isinstance(base.base, np.ndarray):
        base = base.base
    return base

def arrays_share_data(x, y):
    return get_data_base(x) is get_data_base(y) 

arrays_share_data(a, a.compress(b, axis=0))
#>>> False
arrays_share_data(a, a[b])
#>>> False
```

I am simply curious because I perform these operations frequently in my work.  I run python 3.5.2, numpy v 1.11.1, installed via Anaconda.

Comment: You can also play with `np.where` to turn the boolean into an index array, and `np.take` to select rows with that.  All actions produce a copy of the selected values.  Times probably have more to do with calling overhead and generality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tracing `a.compress` through several layers of function calls on the `numpy` `github` I get to

```
/numpy/core/src/multiarray/item_selection.c
PyArray_Compress(PyArrayObject *self, PyObject *condition, int axis,
             PyArrayObject *out)
    # various checks
    res = PyArray_Nonzero(cond);
    ret = PyArray_TakeFrom(self, PyTuple_GET_ITEM(res, 0), axis,
                       out, NPY_RAISE);
```

With your sample arrays, `compress` is the same as doing `where` to get a index array, and then `take`:

```
In [135]: a.shape
Out[135]: (1000000, 4)
In [136]: b.shape
Out[136]: (1000000,)
In [137]: a.compress(b, axis=0).shape
Out[137]: (499780, 4)
In [138]: a.take(np.nonzero(b)[0], axis=0).shape
Out[138]: (499780, 4)
In [139]: timeit a.compress(b, axis=0).shape
100 loops, best of 3: 14.3 ms per loop
In [140]: timeit a.take(np.nonzero(b)[0], axis=0).shape
100 loops, best of 3: 14.3 ms per loop
```

In fact if I use this index array in the [] indexing I get comparable times:

```
In [141]: idx=np.where(b)[0]
In [142]: idx.shape
Out[142]: (499780,)
In [143]: timeit a[idx,:].shape
100 loops, best of 3: 14.6 ms per loop
In [144]: timeit np.take(a,idx, axis=0).shape
100 loops, best of 3: 9.9 ms per loop
```

`np.take` code is more involved since it includes `clip` and `wrap` modes.

[] indexing gets translated into a `__getitem__` call, and through various layers.  I haven't traced that code vary far, but I think it's safe to say that `compress` (or rather `take`) just takes a more direct route to the task, and thus gets a modest speed increase.  A speed difference of 30-50% suggests differences in compiled code details, not something major like `views` vs `copies`, or interpreted vs compiled.

Answer (score 1):

When the indices to select along one axis are specified by a vector of boolean masks, the function compress is an alternative to fancy indexing,
The noticeable speed gain is due to the axis selection being pre-specified, whereas fancy indexing can be used to make arbitrary selections of an array, thus incurs the performance penalty to make this possible.
This is also the cause to the variable speed gain you have experienced.

```
i = np.random.random_sample(n) < .5

b1 = a[i]
b2 = np.compress(i, a, axis=0)

%timeit a[i]
10 loops, best of 3: 59.8 ms per loop
%timeit np.compress(i, a, axis=0)
10 loops, best of 3: 24.1 ms per loop
```

Comment: "thus incurs the performance penalty to make this possible" - this should be a constant penalty that doesn't scale with the array size

Comment: But why can't numpy infer the axis selection just as well from the boolean indexing syntax as it can from the axis argument to `compress`?